# @ symbol breaking angular expression

Tags: javascript, c#, json, angularjs, json.net

The following html breaks because of the @ symbol. What work around is there besides not using the @ sign. I have to use the @ symbol because the json will be generated in a c# web api by using newtonsoft jsonconvert http://www.newtonsoft.com/json from xml. jsonconvert prefixes xml attribute with the @ symbol in the generated json.

How do i fix the @ sign issue? One thing that works for me is message.root.node1["@attr1"]. If possible, please provide a resource that details what symbols are banned in angular variables/expressions.

```
<html ng-app="countryApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js JSON Fetching Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
      countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.message = { "root": { "node1": { "@attr1": "1", "@attr2": "2" }, "node2": { "@attr1": "3", "@attr2": "4" } } }

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
    <h2>Angular.js JSON Fetching Example</h2>

      <span>
        menudatetime {{message.root.node1.@attr1}}
      </span>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Google searching anything with @ symbol is annoying as hell. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `message.root.node1['@attr1']`.

It is basically a JavaScript expression for Angular. `message.root.node1.@attr1` isn't valid javascript...

Comment: I just added a comment in my answer. you are the first so you get the prize

Answer (score 1):

You could switch to bracket notation as a workaround:

```html
<html ng-app="countryApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js JSON Fetching Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
      countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.message = { "root": { "node1": { "@attr1": "1", "@attr2": "2" }, "node2": { "@attr1": "3", "@attr2": "4" } } }

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
    <h2>Angular.js JSON Fetching Example</h2>

      <span>
        menudatetime {{message.root.node1['@attr1']}}
      </span>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the array accessor (bracket notation) in this case:

```
 <span>
        menudatetime {{message.root.node1.["@attr1"]}}
 </span>
```

In terms of docs on what expressions can do, and their limitations, go to https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression in the Angular docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
{{message.root.node1["@attr1"]}}
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/yijehitina/edit?html,output)

From MDN:

**Bracket notation**

```
get = object[property_name];
object[property_name] = set;
```

property_name is a string. The string does not have to be a valid identifier; it can have any value, e.g. "1foo", "!bar!", or even " " (a space).

```
document['createElement']('pre');
```

This does the exact same thing as the previous example.